# Text coming out of menu when i make my screen smaller

Tags: html, css

i am making a site for myself.
I am beginning with the menu but i have a little problem if i make my screen smaller the text is coming out of the menu.

[image: menu]

And here i have the code i have typed in html:

```
<div id="header">


            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Over mij</li>
                    <li>Ervaringen</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div>
```

And css:

```
body 
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(53, 43, 35, 0.70);
}

ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 75%;
}

li
{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Try to read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)

Comment: Add overflow:hidden to the menu id.

Comment: You will need different approach - google 'responsive design'. Header is just start....

Comment: Question is, what do you want it to do when the screen is too small to show everything?

Comment: @andyb Yes to show the full menu if i make screen smaller

Comment: go with bootstrap nav bar..check those link i posted above.

Comment: I would definitely follow the advice from @nevermind and look at _responsive design_. It is difficult to answer the question since the overall site design would need to be considered. Simply saying "show the full menu" is hard to address when there is insufficient screen space. Factors like font-size, overflow, layout, positioning (and more) will affect how the browser reflows the content when the screen is too small to show everything.

Comment: @KipVerslaafde if you are ok with bootstrap then check this one https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/yprL90pz/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove margin-left from ul style

```
ul{
margin: 0px;
}
```

and if you want the menu items to be on the left of the page you just need to add text-aling to ul

```
ul{
margin:0;
text-align:right;
}
```

See your Demo here after edits: https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/k6bu3bt8/1/

And this demo you can also used for responsive design that will work on all devices : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/o89pn61t/

Comment: and if you will make small screen text will go out of box.. right?

Comment: Yes it will go out of box in small screen , but you can see this example which will fix problem in small screen : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/o89pn61t/

Comment: nice one..sorry for my lines but you should mention this in your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you wish to show full menu at even smaller screen what you can do is use media queries.

Like in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/odn0Lzfc I've added following media queries rest your code is same.

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  ul{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  li{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

What it will do is adjust your content for respective screen sizes.

Learn more about media queries here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices

Answer (score -2):

Add word break and white space property to li tag.

```
   li {  word-break: break-word;
        white-space: normal;
    }
```

Comment: please try your solution first then post as answer as its not working at all. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't work here in this case , Just try your solution first